# All latitude and longitude within 1 mile circle area

Tags: google-maps-api, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to generate pins over the map of my database coordinates by using fusion table and I want to generate only within 1 mile area circle around the specific location. To get 1 mile area's coordinates similar to my db coordinates I've to put condition of < and > to fusion table but I don't know how to get all the coordinates within 1 mile area circle or what should be the value for condition in query. Can any one please help me to figure out, it'll really appreciable.

Comment: A detail blog: http://goo.gl/oU7Krf